# PHP "or" not working in multi-part conditional

Tags: php, boolean

I am trying to do a working week detector ie mon - fri:

```
if (($nowday == "thu"||"thu"))
```

gives TRUE when $nowday is sat

```
if (($nowday == "thu"))
```

gives FALSE! $nowday still sat. Obviously that is right. Why am I getting the false true?

Am I crazy or isn't the OR operator in PHP || ?

Comment: Your first if condition isn't right. This is the same case if you do `if(1){echo 'true';}` which will be `true` because it's not being compared to anything.

Comment: OK first guys (and gals?) I am soooooo sorry for not saying thanks earlier. Ihave been meraning too for ages but, y'know stuff keeps getting in the way, then you forget etc.etc. No excuses so sorry but a HUGE thank you.

Comment: Dang this posted prematurely and I timed out on an edit while resaearching some rather nice CSS so .... but a HUGE thank you. I went with the array and it worked like a charm. <BR><BR>

I am still utterly perplexed on operation of the PHP OR operator but will start a new thread for an academic discussion at some stage soon. I will post a note here when I put it up (may be later today). I should also own up that my original post was incredibly vague - but you got me there. Mahalo nui loa and Aloha from Maui :-)

Answer (score 3):

### Why doesn't it work?

**Your conditional expression will *always* evaluate to `TRUE` regardless of the variable value.**

```
if (($nowday == "thu"||"thu"))
```

**Case 1: When `$nowday` is `thu`:**

```
1. (($nowday == "thu") || "thu") // precedence grouping
2. (TRUE || "thu")               // ("thu" == "thu") is TRUE
3. (TRUE || TRUE)                // because non-empty string evaluates to TRUE
4. (TRUE)
```

**Case 2: When `$nowday` is `sat`:**

```
1. (($nowday == "sat") || "thu") // precedence grouping
2. (FALSE || "thu")              // ("thu" == "sat") is FALSE
3. (FALSE || TRUE)               // non-empty string evaluates to TRUE
4. (TRUE)
```

### How to fix this?

If you're simply trying to check if `$nowday` is `thu`, then why do you need to write the condition twice? Just use the following:

```
if ($nowday == "thu")
```

If you need to check if `$nowday` is **either** `thu` or `sat`, you'd write:

```
if ($nowday == "thu" || $nowday == "sat")
```

Alternatively, you could separate the expressions with parentheses. This way, you can be sure of the order in which the conditions are evaluated. If they're not wrapped in parentheses, they're evaluated according to [precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php):

```
if ( ($nowday == "thu") || ($nowday == "sat") )
```

If you want to check for multiple days, then you can use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/in_array):

```
$days = array('thu', 'fri', 'sat', /* ... */);

if (in_array($nowday, $days)) {
    // day is one of the days defined in the array
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (($nowday == "thu"||"thu"))
```

Is saying if `$nowday == "thu"` `OR` if `"thu"`. `if("thu")` is always `TRUE` since the string "thu" is not empty. This is why your conditional statement returns `TRUE` and will always return `TRUE`.

You should write your conditional statement like so:

```
if (($nowday == "thu"|| $nowday == "thu"))
```

But this can be simplified into:

```
if ($nowday == "thu")
```

Comment: But `==` has a higher operator precedence than `||`

Comment: `"thu"||"thu"` is of course `TRUE` but I don't think that is ever being evaluated. It evaluates `($nowday == "thu") || "thu"`